# Почему не отправляются данные в бота телеграм? Ошибок в консоли нет

Tags: javascript, html, css, telegram-bot, axios

Код:

```js
import axios from '/axios';


const TOKEN = "x";
const CHAT_ID = "-x";
const URI_API = `https://api.telegram.org/bot{${TOKEN}}/sendMessage`;

document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    
    let message = `<b> x </b> ${this.name.value}`;

    axios.post(URI_API, {
        chat_id: CHAT_ID,
        parse_mode: 'html',
        text: message
    }).then(res => {
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Может кнопка не нажимается, на которую вы повесили событие клика? Может адрес не правильный. Что происходит во вкладке network браузера?

Comment: это расширение для гугл хром

Comment: возможные причины: неправильный URL API, отсутствие элемента с id 'x', если у вас есть форма для ввода текста с именем 'name' - убедитесь, что она определена корректно, axios подключен не правильно, проблема может быть связана с сервером Telegram - не блокирует ли ваш сервер запросы к API Telegram, у вашего бота нет прав на отправку сообщений в указанный чат или неправильный CHAT_ID.